# Flight Recorder "native" files

Tags: java, profiling, java-mission-control

If I set up a continuous or long-lived timed recording on a JVM, do I ever have to worry about the dump files on the target machine getting too big?  Where are these files stored?

Thx.

Comment: I'm currently running Flight Recorder on a JVM that is running Tomcat.  In this case, these files are stored in $CATALINA_BASE/temp.  This isn't helpful ... what if we're not running Tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a max age or max size for the files, see

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html, the -XX:FlightRecorderOptions section.

You should also use disk=true, and you can specify repository to decide where the files are stored.

(If it doesn't work according to documentation, let me know, some of the docs have been slightly incorrect in the past, and even though I work with this I find it hard to remember all the details...)

Comment: Well, that's about the best collection of Flight Recorder options I've seen in one place.  The stuff on the web is just scattered and inconsistent across many versions.  It's been very hard to find the 'truth.  I'll give these a look and see if they will solve my issues.  Thanks.

Comment: http://hirt.se/blog/?p=370 and other posts by my colleague are also very useful (sometimes more than the docs)